# Why am I getting a straight flow path (stream) in obviously varying terrain -QGIS

Tags: qgis, hydrology, flow-direction, strahler

Does anyone have suggestions on why the streams are sometimes represented as longer straight lines, even though the hillshade and contours generated from the same DTM (filled) clearly indicate that the watercourse should be both elsewhere and meandering (it is correct on much of the network, but some stretches are clearly wrong for lengths even up to 1 km).

[image: The image shows how some paths seem to be flowing correctly while this long stretch -c. 2 km - travels mostly in a straight line]

Comment: Those streamlines look correct to me. You don't say how you generated them, but I assume that you used a "D8" algorithm, where all the water from one cell flows into one of the eight neighbouring cells. These algorithms have the tendency for streams to "snap" in 45° steps, which is what's happening on your wide slopes.

Comment: @Jake, can you suggest another algorithm to be used in such a case?

Comment: @marcm: You could use GRASS's [`r.flow` algorithm](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.flow.html)  with the (default) "multiple flow direction" option